# Elasticsearch Java Client : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, elasticsearch

It's probably one of the most talked about question.I am using java Client for ES and it is giving me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:217)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:265)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.java:46)
    at ConfigureES.<init>(ConfigureES.java:25)
    at ReadFromCsvAndImportToEs.<init>(ReadFromCsvAndImportToEs.java:83)
    at ReadFromCsvAndImportToEs.main(ReadFromCsvAndImportToEs.java:22)
```

Some answers for this question says it's not about memory, it's about how much thread your os can handle, other says pump your `java heap`.I am not sure what is the cause of this problem.
my code to index data on ES is

```
public ReadFromCsvAndImportToEs() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, ParseException {
  BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(
                new ConfigureES().client,
                new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeBulk(long executionId,BulkRequest request) {  }

                    @Override
                    public void afterBulk(long executionId,BulkRequest request,BulkResponse response) {  }

                    @Override
                    public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {

                    }
                })
                .setBulkActions(10000)
                .setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(5, ByteSizeUnit.MB))
                .setFlushInterval(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(5))
                .setConcurrentRequests(1)
                .setBackoffPolicy(
                        BackoffPolicy.exponentialBackoff(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(100), 3))
                .build();


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/months/modified/nov-17-dec-17.csv"));

        br.readLine();
        String line="";
        String[] lines;
        int i=0;
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            lines = line.split(",");

            String store_code = lines[3];
            String bill_date = lines[22];
            String cart_id = md5(lines[20]).substring(0,15).toUpperCase();
            String bill_no = md5(lines[22]+"-"+lines[3]).substring(1,18).toUpperCase();
            String division = lines[21];
            String icode = md5(lines[33]).substring(0,5).toUpperCase();
            String mrp = lines[25];
            String qty = lines[27];
            String totalAmt = lines[35];
            String section = lines[2];
            String department = lines[19];

            bulkProcessor.add( new IndexRequest("index", "type")
                    .source(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                            .field("store_code", store_code)
                            .field("bill_date", bill_date)
                            .field("bill_no", bill_no)
                            .field("cart_id", cart_id)
                            .field("division", division)
                            .field("icode", icode)
                            .field("mrp", Double.parseDouble(mrp.toString()))
                            .field("qty", Double.parseDouble(qty.toString()))
                            .field("totalAmt", Double.parseDouble(totalAmt.toString()))
                            .field("section", section)
                            .field("department", department)
                            .endObject()
                    )
            );

        }

        bulkProcessor.close();
        catch (Exception e) 
        System.out.println("closing client");
        new ConfigureES().client.close();
```

Some people suggested to make change ES configuration to limit thread pool, but `PYTHON CLIENT WORKS FINE`. Why is it the problem with `java client`. So I am not sure if should make any changes to my ES configuration. So I am posting my client machine configuration
my `lscpu`

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               800.039
CPU max MHz:           3500.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              5999.85
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Also if this helps `ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128065
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 128065
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks
```

and `ps -eLF| grep -c java` shows `208`. my file size is `91.5mb` with `817764` lines. I need help on this topic. I am not sure if this is related to memory or something else and on my client machine or server.

Comment: Your piece of code creates three `ConfigureES` objects, and at least one is never closed. Consider using the same object . Also, your `BulkProcessor` object doesn't seem to be used .

Comment: sorry, I update my question. I am using bulkprocessor.You were right about my client. I was over looking my client creation and creating 3. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the maximum number of processes your shall can have. You can fix it by increasing the number processes that a shell allowed to have by running this from the command line of the shell used to run the client.

```
ulimit -u 10000
```

Or, you can add it to the startup shell script of the client.